# AngularJS and ui-grid error: Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the sample code from http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable to implement a row-editable ui grid.

The sample code works fine when I download it and run it locally, but it throws this error when I try to implement it within the larger project our team is building:

```
angular.js:12330 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives 
[input (module: app), uiGridEditor] asking for new/isolated scope on: 
<input type="text" ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor="" 
ng-model="row.entity['Brand']" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">...

at angular.js:68
at assertNoDuplicate (angular.js:8424)
at applyDirectivesToNode (angular.js:7803)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7459)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7471)
at compileNodes (angular.js:7471)
at compile (angular.js:7366)
at createEditor (ui-grid.js:16223)
at beginEditAfterScroll (ui-grid.js:16230)
at ui-grid.js:16029
```

Here is the template used to implement the grid:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="ibox-content" ng-controller="myEditController">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav 
class="grid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the controller:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('myEditController', myEditController);

function myEditController($scope, $http, $cookies, $location, $rootScope, $timeout, $interval, $state, $q, myService) {
var model = this;
var myData = {};

$scope.gridOptions = {};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  { name: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true },
  { name: 'Brand', enableCellEdit: true },
  { name: 'Season', enableCellEdit: true },
 { name: 'Season', enableCellEdit: true }
];

$scope.saveEdits = function (rowEntity) {

    alert(rowEntity);
};

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    //set gridApi on scope
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveEdits);
};

get();

function get() {
    myService.getList().then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
            myData = response;
            $scope.gridOptions.data = myData;
        }
        else {
            model.isError = true;
            model.errorMessage = "No data Found";
        }

    },
    function (error, status) {
        model.isError = true;
        model.errorMessage = "There was an error retrieving data. Please contact the system administrator";
    });
};
}
```

I'm not sure where the conflict is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: blind guess : change input to a simple div element. If you need an input to bind validity to your form, create an hidden input that will have the same ng-model than your grid.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I guess. The grid is already in a div element. Unless you're referring to the error message that mentions "input type=text," but I don't control that, it's handled within the ui-grid.js file. I need to figure out how I have multiple directives making a claim on the same item at once.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the error. In this case it was not because of a duplicate-named directive, it was because this bit of code was chained to angular.module('app') in the global app.js file:

```
.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        ...
        //code to check for changes in textbox value
```

So that's where the collision was taking place.

Hopefully this helps somebody else at some point. Check the global settings!